# Content is not added in one of the appended textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function below where the if statement works when it comes to adding content into a single textarea when clicking the "Add" button:

```
function addwindow(questionText) { 

    if(window.console) console.log();

    if($(plusbutton_clicked).attr('id')=='mainPlusbutton') { 
        $('#mainTextarea').val(questionText); 
        } else { 
            $(plusbutton_clicked).parent('td').next('td.question').find('textarea.textAreaQuestion').val(questionText);
            }

    $.modal.close(); 
    return false;
}
```

Below is the code for the single textarea and it's plus button:

```
<form id="QandA" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post">

<div id="detailsBlock">
<table id="question">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Question:</td> 
    <td rowspan="3">
        <textarea class="questionTextArea" id="mainTextarea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<table id="plus" align="center">
<tr>
<th>
<a onclick="return plusbutton();">
<img src="Images/plussign.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt="Look Up Previous Question" class="plusimage" id="mainPlusbutton" name="plusbuttonrow"/>
</a>
<span id="plussignmsg">(Click Plus Sign to look <br/> up Previous Questions)</span>
</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

The problem is the else statement is not working when it comes to adding content within one of the appended textareas below. What I want is that if a user clicks on a Plus button next to one of the appended textarea and adds a content by clicking on the "Add" button, the textarea which belongs in the same row as the plus button which was clicked on will add the content. What do I need to change in order to do this?

Below is the code whch shows the textareas and plus buttons which are appended:

```
    var plusbutton_clicked;

 function insertQuestion(form) {


var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'></tr>");
var $plusrow = $("<td class='plusrow'></td>");
var $question = $("<td class='question'></td>");


 $('.questionTextArea').each( function() {

 var $this = $(this);
var $questionText = $("<textarea class='textAreaQuestion'></textarea>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
.attr('value',$this.val());

 $question.append($questionText);

});

 $('.plusimage').each( function() {

var $this = $(this);
var $plusimagerow = $("<a onclick='return plusbutton();'><img src='Images/plussign.jpg' width='30' height='30' alt='Look Up Previous Question' class='imageplus'/></a>").attr('name',$this.attr('name')+"[]")
.attr('value',$this.val());

$plusrow.append($plusimagerow);

 });

$tr.append($plusrow);
$tr.append($question);
$tbody.append($tr);                     

}
```

You can view application [here](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable2.php). Please follow the steps to use the application:

1. Click on "Add Question" button, then will add a textarea within a new row.
2. Click on the "Green Plus" button within the table row you just added, a modal window will appear.
3. In modal window it displays a search bar, in search bar type in "AAA" and click on "Search" button
4. Results will appear of your search, click on "Add" button to add a row. You will find out modal window is closed but the content from the "Question" field is not added in the textarea within the row you clicked on the green plus button

If you did the steps in the top textarea (the one above the horizontal line), then it does work, it just doesn't work for textarea which you have just added

Comment: At least you're trying to code it now instead of just repeating the same question.. Did you try replacing `<a onclick='return plusbutton();'>` by `<a href='#'>` as I suggested a couple of your questions ago? You already have event delegation with `live()` bound to those images which pass the element as parameter to your `plusbutton()` function, which atm your `a`'s `onclick` doesn't.

Comment: you mean, you want to append the text, and not replace it?

Comment: @ParthThakkar I do mean replace the text actually. so lets say the textarea in the appended row saud "What is 2+2?", but then I want to change the question by selecting a question such as "What is 45+45?", then it should replace "What is 2+2?" with what is "What is 45+45?" in the textarea

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I did do what you stated but it did not work, it wouldn't open up the modal window when I remove the onclick and change it with href='#'. Is it because in the live function it is `$('.plusimage').each( function() {` while the class for each appended textarea is .imageplus?

Comment: can you please fiddle it out...you know it's really a long piece of code, so fiddle would help.

Comment: I'd believe your `.live` is not working inside your modal because you're opening it inside an `iframe` as far as I remember.. Try `"<a onclick='return plusbutton(this);'>` or `"<a onclick='return plusbutton($(this));'>`, also post the link to the application again.. I have to sleep but someone may help you. Also, when you edit your answer, your question is automatically bumped up to the top of the list, you don't have to ask it over and over and over and over by the #324234234 time again.. You'd also earn some rep from upvotes if you edit your question to follow your progress. G'night, GL.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Ok I will keep that in mind :) Goodnight

Comment: @ParthThakkar I will send you URL to application, give me 2 mins

Comment: @ParthThakkar I have included URL to application in question above. please follow steps in order to use it :)

Comment: @ParthThakkar It's Ok, it been figured out.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it, I will also mark the answer in the previous question as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the element which your `plusbutton()` function expects as parameter, that's why the function can't find the sibling element to get its contents. Try:

```
<a onclick='return plusbutton(this);'>
```